# How get current login user in ViewComponent Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I Use a ViewComponent for render sidebar in some page. I need current login User for some action, how can get User in ViewComponent? Of course I can pass as a parameter from view to InvokeAsync method, but I'm looking for a better way.

```
public class SideBarViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

    public ProfileSideBarViewComponent(UserManager<User> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
         //How access User

         _userManager.GetUserId(User);

        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In ViewComponent you can access to user by `UserClaimsPrincipal` instead of User property.

In ViewComponent:

```
public abstract class ViewComponent
{
    public ClaimsPrincipal UserClaimsPrincipal { get; }
    ....
}
```

In Controller:

```
[Controller]
public abstract class ControllerBase
{
    protected ControllerBase();

    public ClaimsPrincipal User { get; }
    
    ....
}
```

Comment: They should be more consistent.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you have access to the current [HttpContext](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/HttpContext.cs),  from which you can [get the Current Claims Identity](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/security/claims/ClaimsIdentity.cs) which implements `IIdentity`.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
var user = this.HttpContext.User;
```

Answer (score 4):

you have access to the Request so you can get it like this:

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
     _userManager.GetUserId(Request.HttpContext.User);

    return View();
}
```